# How to query has_one through relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

My models:
metro_station.rb

```
class MetroStation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :metro_line
  has_one :city, through: :metro_line, autosave: false
end
```

metro_line.rb`

```
class MetroLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  has_many :metro_stations
end
```

city.rb

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :metro_lines
end
```

When I run:
`MetroStation.where(city: City.first)`
I get

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column metro_stations.city_id does not exist
: SELECT "metro_stations".* FROM "metro_stations" WHERE "metro_stations"."city_id" = 1
(pry) output error: #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column metro_stations.city_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...CT "metro_stations".* FROM "metro_stations" WHERE "metro_sta...
```

While this query works:
`MetroStation.joins(:metro_line).where(metro_lines: {city_id: 1})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out why your first approach doesn't work type in

```
MetroStation.where(city: City.first).to_sql
```

You should see something like

```
... WHERE metro_stations.city_id = 1
```

forming part of the query. The MetroStation model simply doesn't have the city_id attribute, as a result your first approach forms an invalid SQL statement.

The join works since it is filtering on the MetroLine table which has the relationship to the City model in form of the city_id field.

Nothing wrong with your models it is just the way Rails generates the SQL statements which in the world of SQL makes sense.

A has_many relationship on City to MetroStation through MetroLine delivers the desired results for your question (which metro stations are in a city).

#### Example

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :metro_lines
  has_many :metro_stations, through: :metro_lines
end

class MetroLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  has_many :metro_stations
end

class MetroStation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :metro_line
  has_one :city, through: :metro_line
end


# Return all metro stations for a city
# * assuming City has name 'name' field
london_stations = City.find_by_name('London').metro_stations
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I understand your explanation but I think that `has_one :city` should enable me to query with `where(city: <city>)`? Am I not correct?

Comment: No, this is not how Rails works. The city relationship on MetroStation however is useful but it doesn't do the join. It provides access to city for a single instantiated MetroStation object. Rails submits a query to the database server as a result. David Aldridge's answer below gives you a handle on the data you are looking for through the City model. In this case Rails is creating the JOIN: SELECT metro_stations.* FROM metro_stations INNER JOIN metro_lines ON metro_stations.metro_line_id = metro_lines.id WHERE metro_lines.city_id = 1

Comment: Could you add code from David Albridge's answer, so I can accept your answer?

Comment: I guess leemour was as much interested to understand why MetroStation.where(city: City.first) doesn't work as to find a way to achieve his objective.Please give credit to David in case you wanted to find a way to select those stations based on the city rather that to gain understanding on the where clause.

Comment: @smile2day I'd prefer to give credit to you as you provided good explanation. But for future users, I think it would be useful to have a working solution in accepted answer.

Comment: @leemour: You are right. Future users may find a complete example more helpful - I added it to the answer. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

City should also:

```
has_many :metro_stations, :through => :metro_lines
```

And then you write:

```
City.first.metro_stations
```